# How to create a virtual PulseAudio stereo source from the Left Mic Channel & the Right Monitor Channel?

Tags: pulseaudio

I have just one sound card. 2 ins & 2 outs.

I want to make a new virtual stereo source to record from that is:

- the left mic input panned hard left,
- and whatever is currently playing on the right output panned hard right

I know it must be possible, and I can get partway there, but not quite getting it.

I've been trying permutations of load-module commands in `~/.config/pulse/default.pa`

Help!